# Associate OpenCL device with NVAPI device

Tags: c, dictionary, opencl, nvapi

I am trying to associate the OpenCL GPU devices with NVAPI devices which I get using `NvAPI_EnumPhysicalGPUs` in the Multi-GPU system.

The thing is, I can use `clGetDeviceInfo` with `CL_DEVICE_VENDOR_ID` which is always unique and it is the best way, and I can retrieve the vendor from the `NvAPI_SYS_GetChipSetInfo`. But it is not associated with the `NvPhysicalGpuHandle` which I get from `NvAPI_EnumPhysicalGPUs`. Is there any way to associate this?

Of course, I can just use name, but this is not good.

Comment: How about `NvAPI_GPU_GetBusId` and friends?

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae i can use this on NVAPI side sure, but how do i get the Bus id in OpenCL? `clGetDeviceInfo` doesn't seem to have any definition to return the bus id in the documentation page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to do it. In OpenCL there is a poor documented feature for some reason. You need to call `clGetDeviceInfo` with constant `0x4008` and it will give you the bus id for the following device handle.

```
cl_uint busID;
clGetDeviceInfo(device,0x4008,sizeof(cl_uint), &busID,NULL);
printf("%d",busID);
```

On NvApi side use `NvAPI_GPU_GetBusId`. Then you can associate the handles by comapring the buses.